# List MySQL enum in Java

Tags: java, mysql, enums

Is there a way to get all possible values from a MySQL enum column?

The [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html) says the MySQL enum type is returned as a Java String, so I basically would like a way to get all possible strings I can pass when querying a table with such an enum.

I couldn't immediately find anything when I was looking through the metadata returned for such a column, but since enum isn't standard SQL, I'm not sure it's even possible... any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SHOW COLUMNS FROM Table LIKE field` returns something like:
`enum('value1','value2','value3','value4')`. Parse out the enum values from the string with a regular expression (`"/'(.*?)'/"`).

Comment: This regexp will fail if we have defined `O'Really` as value for example. You should check for escaping backslashes.